# migrate a MU sub blog to a single install

Tags: multisite

I would like to convert one of my WordPress multisite blogs back to a single install on another server.
it's not the main site but one of the subdomains. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Export function.

It's just like taking your blog off WordPress.com and switching to the .org standalone.

'Cept you also have access to the themes & plugins files.

Comment: thanks for answering on twitter and here! actually I was thinking of migrating the content and settings like with backupbuddy, you don't have to reinstall plugins and reconfigure all the menus and widgets

Comment: Backupbuddy grabs the whole network.

You can go into the db and grab that blog's options table, rename it for the new install, and dump it in there. that will move all your widget & plugins settings. Also grab any extra tables different plugins added.

Comment: Andrea, is there a step by step guide somewhere that you know of?

Comment: No guide, it's on my list to write up, but it's relatively straightforward. Export the posts, grab copies of the theme & plugins, snag the wp_X_options table if you need it. If you have a bunch of users to move too, that gets a little trickier, but it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bet my life on the export function.  It's worth a try though, just check your data afterwards.  Export doesn't move images, media files, etc.  So if you have a lot of images, you might wish you used relative URLs ;-)

Comment: it seemed to move the images ok, when you import, you can check a box to import all the images as well as posts

Answer (score -1):

the codex has a great article called "[Migrating Multiple Blogs into WordPress 3.0 Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite)" making it simple to follow steps that should get you Migrating in no time.

Comment: it's the opposite I want to do, but thanks

Comment: Sorry just read the question again